# objectcontext & dbcontext differences when binding

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-database-first

I have been using ObjectContext in my projects, but now I'm trying DbContext, I found some differences that I don't understand when binding to a datasource, for example

## USING DbContext

I bind datasource like this

```
DbSet<Client> Clients = ctx.Client;
Clients.Load();
bsClients.DataSource = Clients().Local.ToBindingList();
bsClientPhones.DataSource = ((Client)bsClients.Current).Phone; // this line doesn't work
```

When I bind "bsClientPhones" like that, the grid doesn't show changes when add or delete, until I save and reload data. I can't convert it to Local or Bindinglist.

I don't know if this is the right way to use DbContext
Please could someone guide me? I have been reading many documentation but I'm lost.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to implement ObservableCollection at entity level and provide the same to your grids.

```
   public class ObservableListSource<T> : ObservableCollection<T>, IListSource
        where T : class
    {
        private IBindingList _bindingList;

        bool IListSource.ContainsListCollection { get { return false; } }

        IList IListSource.GetList()
        {
            return _bindingList ?? (_bindingList = this.ToBindingList());
        }
    } 

this.categoryBindingSource.DataSource =
                _context.Categories.Local.ToBindingList();
```

After every change, you need to call `this.categoryDataGridView.Refresh();`

Here is the quick demo I can give with the DataGridView. The same will apply to GridView for Web form.

https://github.com/codebased/tm/tree/master/WindowsFormTestConsole

Comment: The link you provided doesn't work (unless you intended to show up the "404-Jedi" page ...)